# Python mechanize connection failed issue

Tags: python, mechanize, web-crawler, python-requests

I am running a crawler, it's working fine in MAC and Ubuntu system.
When I am running it in windows it results following stack trace:

```
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_opener.py", line 193, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1170, in https_open
    return self.do_open(conn_factory, req)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1118, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Comment: Is it a specific URL which causes it to throw this error? `URLError` looks like a timeout error. Use `try..except` to handle this error if it turns out not to be fatal.

Comment: Put the part of code, that makes request, here.

Comment: Are you using the same python and mechanize versions on all of the systems?

Comment: You might have more luck if you post a complete code snippet that consistently reproduces the problem. I'm with the other commenters, in that I'm guessing there's something else dodgy going on outside Mechanize. Admittedly, Windows forks differently than *nix systems, and maybe that's part of it, but it's almost certainly not the whole puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

I heavily doubt that the problem is connected to your system. To fix the problem, I would recommend:

1. Check your **mechanize** version. Older versions might handle requests differently.
2. Investigate `set_handle_robots` and `addheaders`. Issue might be connected to too many requests per IP. (I suspect that this is the real problem.)
3. Check **error handling**. Like described in a comment above you should add proper error handling anyway.

If none of the described solutions above works, please provide the code which is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

From the error I deduce that the server you're trying to connect to is not allowing your connection.

Try to use `telnet` to double check you can connect to the `URL/IP:PORT` you are requesting:

```
telnet <ip> <port>
```

PS: Just in case, don't use ping you check the connectivity as you're not testing the port.